# Using pam_succeed_if to restrict user login to single group

Tags: login, pam

I'm running Debian 9.  What I want to do is restrict user logins to uids that are members of the "goodgroup" group. I forget where I got this solution originally, but this is what I have in my /etc/pam.d/common-account:

```
.
.
.
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
account [success=1 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]    pam_unix.so 
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
account requisite           pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
account required            pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
account required            pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=1000
account sufficient          pam_localuser.so 

# >>> This is where I'm trying to do it <<<
account requisite                       pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup goodgroup

account [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore]    pam_sss.so 
account [success=ok new_authtok_reqd=done ignore=ignore user_unknown=ignore auth
info_unavail=ignore default=bad]    pam_ldap.so minimum_uid=1000
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

Let's say I have a uid "baduid" that's not in the required group. What I'd like to happen is that trying "su baduid" as root should fail completely. What actually happens is that the su is successful but baduid has no associated home directory.

Here's what I see in the log file when I do "su baduid":

```
May  3 16:08:03 myhost su[3014]: pam_succeed_if(su:account): requirement "user ingroup goodgroup" not met by user "baduid"
May  3 16:08:03 myhost su[3014]: Successful su for baduid by root
May  3 16:08:03 myhost su[3014]: + /dev/pts/0 root:baduid
May  3 16:08:03 myhost su[3014]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user baduid by root(uid=0)
May  3 16:08:03 myhost su[3014]: pam_systemd(su:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a session
```

Comment: Have you tried using the auth version instead of account?

Comment: Thanks for responding, and sorry for taking to long to answer. I tried putting the line in the auth file, making appropriate alterations. It didn't do any good.

Comment: It's a bit late, but maybe using `pam_access` as [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/110298/restricting-account-logins-using-ldap-and-pam) is more successful?